# Converting plain text data to json

Tags: javascript

I have some data that I am trying to process with javascript.

```
DATA:
A.         Category one
1.          item one 
2.          item two
B.         Category two
3.          item three
4.          item four
C.         Category three
5.          item five
6.          item six

DESIRED OUTPUT:
[{
"Category one":["item one", "item two"],
"Category two":["item three", "item four"],
"Category three":["item five", "item six"]
}]
```

Is there a library that will help me with text parsing in javascript?

```
THIS IS AS FAR AS I GOT:

function parseFormat(str) {
var arr = [];
str.split('\n').forEach(function (line) {
    var obj = {};
     line.split('.').forEach(function (item) {
        if (isNaN(item)) {
            // ??
        } else {

        }
    });
    return ?;
});
}
```

Help? Thanks

Comment: I have written the complete function below. Have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete `function`. Please have a look at the code below.

> **Function to parse the string**
>
> ```
> function parseFormat(strArg) {
>   var
>     category,
>     output = {},  // Output
>     str = strArg.trim();  // Remove unwanted space before processing
>
>   str.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
>     var item = line.split('.');
>     if (item[0].match(/\d/)) {  // Match a decimal number
>         // Remove unwanted space & push
>         output[category].push(item[1].trim());
>     } else if (item[0].match(/\D/)) {  // Match UPPERCASE alphabet
>         // Remove unwanted space
>         category = item[1].trim();
>         output[category] = []
>       }
>     });
>   return output;
> }
> ```
>
> **Input string**
>
> ```
> // ES6 Template Strings to define multiline string
> var str = `
>   A.         Category one
>   1.          item one
>   2.          item two
>   B.         Category two
>   3.          item three
>   4.          item four
>   C.         Category three
>   5.          item five
>   6.          item six
> `;
> ```
>
> **Function call**
>
> ```
> // Final output Array
> var finalOutput = [];
> // Parse input string
> var parseStr = parseFormat(str);
>
> finalOutput.push(parseStr);
>
> // Desired JSON output
> console.log(JSON.stringify(finalOutput));
> ```

You can look at the Browser Console for the desired JSON output.

Hope it helps!

Comment: There ya go. You thought of removing the 'for each' for the line split.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to get the information out of the file format and into some variables. It isn't a complete solution. Though once you get the information into variables you can figure out how to json it.

```
var category;
var items;
var item = line.split('.'); //Don't use the forEach on the line split.
if (item[0].match(/\d/) ) {
        // match a decimal number
        items = item[1];
    } else if (item[0].match(/\D/) )  {
        //match a letter
        category = item[1];
    }
```