# How do I convert list to json using C#

Tags: c#, json, message

I need to convert storage queue messages as per the following sample to json.

```
DeviceId: "a4592037"
DeviceName: "device3"
FirmwareVersion: "0.1.23"
MfgDate: "01/02/208"
Level: "normal"
DeviceUptime: "323234"
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Tobias I know it can be accomplished easily with Javascript. Unfortunately, I can't use it since I have several custom C# modules that I need to reference. I have tried most of the operations from Newtonsoft. I am going to set the queue text to dynamic and create an object.

Answer (score 3):

Try out the JSON library from Newtonsoft. With that you can just use:

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject)`

Details at: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

NOTE: The data provided by the user is in plain text and not an object model, and as such will return new line characters. To Combat this:

`string convertMeDaddy = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject)
 convertMeDaddy = convertMeDaddy.replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");`

(the above is if it uses the new line indicator, otherwise change system.enviroment.newline to "\\r\n"

Comment: I tried it.  "DeviceId: \"a4592037\"\r\nDeviceName: \"device3\"\r\nFirmwareVersion: \"0.1.23\"\r\nMfgDate: \"01/02 /208\"\r\nLevel: \"normal\"\r\nDeviceUptime: \"323234\""

Comment: That seems to indicate you may be using a framework on top that possibly sorts the messages. Are you able to add a formatting override to the JsonConvert and check the output: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject, Formatting.None);

Comment: I added the formatter;  "DeviceId: \"a4592037\"\r\nDeviceName: \"device3\"\r\nFirmwareVersion: \"0.1.23\"\r\nMfgDate: \"01/02/208\"\r\nLevel: \"normal\"\r\nDeviceUptime: \"323233\""

Comment: What type of app are you creating it in (webAPI, .Net etc.) and how are you sending the object to whatever controller is handling the data (posting data from a view, posting via jquery etc.)

Comment: function app using a queue trigger

Comment: Built on any framework, or straight C# (WebAPI attempts to parse json itself as do some jquery libraries) Pretty much the \r\n tokens mean that your object has been parsed at some point, meaning the serialize is reparsing and adding linebreaks. Technically you could run a string.replace for \r\n but getting to the top of the issue would be better.

Comment: One more option as well, can you check the output of
string meOlJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject);
string test = meOlJson.ToString(Formatting.None);
console.log(test);

Comment: I agree. Next step is to convert the json to a byte array

Comment: same return value

Comment: cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: Then afraid unless you can find what action is pre-serializing your data, the next best option would be to do the new serialize then a string replace. If you just took your object and did a .ToString(); what is the result of that (i.e. YourObject.ToString();)

Comment: The Azure Storage Queue message is plain text. The sample above is what the message is It is not an object

Comment: AHHHHHH that actually changes everything. Sorry i thought your data was a model object not plain text. You're in for a bit of a nightmare in that case. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284778/converting-plain-text-into-json) OR (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986986/converting-plain-text-data-to-json)

Comment: function processed a request.DeviceId: "a4592037"
DeviceName: "device3"
FirmwareVersion: "0.1.23"
MfgDate: "01/02/208"
Level: "normal"
DeviceUptime: "323233"

Comment: Has to be in C#. It's for a POC

Comment: Those were for an indicator of what you need to do, just because its plain text. data like that in c# if it was a model, would be dealt with immediately with any number of json conversion classes. Because its plain text ,you'll need to create a function to convert your plain text into a mode that can be accepted. So for this situation, create a new function yourself, OR, use the jsonconvert as in my answer, then run a string.replace on the result, ill update my answer to show

Comment: I am going to set the string to dynamic and create an object.

Comment: var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myQueueItem); 
            var device = new Devices
            {
                DeviceId = temp.DeviceId,
                DeviceName = temp.DeviceName,
                DeviceUptime = temp.DeviceUptime,
                FirmwareVersion = temp.FirmwareVersion,
                Level = temp.Level,
                MfgDate = temp.MfgDate
            };

            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(device);

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myQueueItem);

var device = new Devices
    {
    DeviceId = temp.DeviceId,
    DeviceName = temp.DeviceName,
    DeviceUptime = temp.DeviceUptime,
    FirmwareVersion = temp.FirmwareVersion,
    Level = temp.Level,
    MfgDate = temp.MfgDate
    };

 var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(device);
```